# Display PDF stream returned from controller in new window

Tags: javascript, ajax, pdf, view

I am working on a project and I need to display a pdf in a new tab, I have a controller which gets the pdf from a reporting service as a `byte[]`.

```
var data = Search(search_info);
var stream = new MemoryStream(data, 0, data.Length, true, true);    
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=\"\"" + "caseoverview" + ".pdf" + "");
Response.ContentType = MimeTypes.ApplicationPdf;
Response.OutputStream.Write(data1, 0, Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length));
Response.Flush();
return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");
```

I am using Ajax to call the controller:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Controller", null,
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "post",
                OnComplete = "OnCompleteMethod",
                OnFailure = "OnFailtureMethod"
            }))
        {

            <div id="query-filter" class="filters">
                @Html.Partial("QueryFilter", Model)
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-md-offset-8">
                    <button class="btn btn-submit btn-block" type="submit">Find</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                    <button class="btn btn-submit btn-block" type="reset">Reset</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

And the javascript for the success method is:

```
function OnCompleteMethod(dataq, status) {
    if (status === "success") {

        var w = window.open("data:application/pdf, " + escape(dataq.responseText));
        w.document.write(dataq.responseText);
        w.document.close();
}
}
```

And this is what I am getting in the new tab:

[image]

Can someone please help me with this problem, and explain to me what I am doing wrong or what I am missing from the solution.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve the problem with a different approach, instead of using the Ajax call I did just this javascript function:

```
function reportPrinter() {
var myParamether= $('#paramether').val();
window.open('/MyController/ReportPrinterMethod?report=reportview&paramether=' + myParamether, 'ReportView', '');
```

}

and in the Controller I change the method for this approach:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ReportPrinterMethod(string myParamether)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View();

        var data = GetDataReport(myParamether); //Return a byte[] with the pdf content.

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=\"\"" + "reportview" + ".pdf" + "");
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(data.Length));
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
        return View();
    }
```

And that fixed the problem.

Comment: I have almost the same issue, but I need to open the pdf in a modal popup. This will open it in a new browser window. 

I tried to change the action to return a partial view but that does not work. Is there a way to have javascript open the file on the same page?